# Combine results from query in one pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I have some mdb databases with the same structure and different data. I did a loop to do the same query in all those databases usign Querytable. 
The first issue is this code creates a new Querytable for each mdb (I delete it after the loop but I don't know if there is a better way to do that).
The second issue is that all the information should be datasource for a pivot table. When I run the code below, I have an error because "I'm trying to overwrite a pivot table"

Could you help me, please? What I really need to do is execute the same query in some mdb files and put data together as one pivot table

```
For i = 1 To UBound(strPath)
varConn = "ODBC;DBQ=" + strPath(i) + ";Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}"
With Worksheets(wksDestino).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=varConn, Destination:=Worksheets(wksDestino).Cells(iLastRow, 1))
    .FieldNames = bHeader
    .CommandText = varSQL
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = bHeader
End With
iLastRow = Worksheets(wksDestino).Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
bHeader = False
Next i
```

The problem is this is datasource for a pivot table

Comment: So... I found a solution (I have no idea if it's a good one, but it works). I kept QueryTables being added every iteration and after that, I delete all of them. And abourt the data source issue, I saw that I wasn't updating the DataSource from pivotcache with the new number of rows. Since I've done that, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Untested** - this answer will help with the first half of your post.

Before you Add a new **QueryTable** each time, you can Set A QueryTable variable type to your QueryTable, if it doesn't exist it will then go and add it. If the QueryTable already exists, it will just refresh the data.

```
Dim QryTbl      As QueryTable

' if the QryTbl doesn't exist, create it first
On Error Resume Next
Set QryTbl = Worksheet(wksDestino).QueryTables("My_Query_Table_Name")  ' modify this line according to the name you want to give your Query Table

On Error GoTo 0
If QryTbl Is Nothing Then
      Set QryTbl = Worksheet(wksDestino).QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:=rstRecordset, _
        Destination:=Range("A1"))
        QryTbl.Name = "My_Query_Table_Name"  ' modify the name according to your needs      
Else
    ' just refresh the QueryTable data
    QryTbl.Refresh True
End If
```

Comment: I changed part of the code for something like you suggest and, now, I don't have a lot of query tables anymore. But, unfortunately, it doesn't work like i wish....  Now, the information is overwritten and only the last query is kept.  I need information be kept for all mdb files in loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the tables in the .CommandText SQL if they have the same column names:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 IN 'C:\Database1.mdb' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table2 IN 'C:\Database2.mdb' UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table3 IN 'C:\Database3.mdb'
```